# Why do urls that get redirected to mobile versions of a website often lose their full paths and/or query strings?

Tags: http, url, redirect, mobile, browser

Here is an example of a scenario that I find occurs frequently:

Let's say I am on a mobile device and I navigate to the following example url (this is one of many examples- I do not want the moderators to think I am asking a question about Florsheim's website :)  ):

http://www.florsheim.com/shop/style/13113-200.html

When I hit the site I am redirected to the mobile version of the page after which time the path /shop/style/... is lost and I remain on the mobile home page.

What's going on here to cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens because the website is basically two completely different websites, one that gets served to computers and one that gets served to mobile devices. The 'mobile check' usually happens when you hit the non-mobile site and is done with Javascript.

[image: XKCD Mobile to Server Comic]

However, the Javascript method requires you to map out all of the directories/define some system for mapping how page urls on the original site maps to pages on the mobile site. There are three main reasons that pages don't get mapped correctly:

- People just haven't bothered doing a full mapping, for a long time developers were just providing the basics for phone viewing, they didn't think that many people would really use it.
- Sometimes they did do a full mapping, but then the folder structure changed and they never updated. This happen a lot when the mobile site is very different then the normal site. A mistake many websites made.
- Sometimes the mobile version just doesn't have everything. Again, a problem caused because developers just wanted to get something mobile up, but didn't want to convert *every page*.

Now it might seem like you should just be able to take the url and keep it exactly the same, but pointed at the mobile sub-domain, that isn't so hard right?

What often happens is that the url is already being mangled in a `.htaccess` file because the website is on some platform of another. For example,

```
http://www.florsheim.com/shop/style/13113-200.html
```

Might get turned into

```
http://www.florsheim.com/shop/?category=style&itemid=13113-200
```

If they aren't careful, and don't reconstruct the query, their Javascript might just redirect to the base url `http://www.florsheim.com/shop/` and forget to pass in the category and itemid. Or they might do it in the wrong format and you just get kicked to a home page.

This type of 'two website' approach is not considered the best, and is often plagued with the kind of issues you are describing. The 'best' way to handle all devices now-a-days is to use a '[responsive site design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)'. This is just one site with CSS and Javascript that adjusts the layout to accommodate all sorts of screen sizes.

Comment: +1 for the xkcd comic.  Seems like the root cause is laziness.  I can maybe forgive the problem when it happens on some ecommerce site or something but when it's a content/media site it seems ridiculous to not do the work - you just lose readers.

Comment: A follow-up - it seems simple (I know, everything *seems* simple if you're on the outside) to include script in each page to check the user agent for mobile and then redirect to the appropriate mobile page.  Who knows.  What I still don't understand is why I see this happen in cases where the desktop and mobile URLs are the *same*.  In these cases the mobile check is obviously being done but the paths and/or query strings are still lost.  What might cause that?